# Need to add elements of an array iteratively in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you please help me write a python program (using Python 3.4) to add elements of a number iteratively till the sum reaches to a single digit. My program is as follows:

```
import random
import sys
import os

n = input('Please enter the number: ')
ar = list(map(int, str(n)))
sm = sum(ar)
ar_sm = list(map(int, str(sm)))
total_num = sum(ar_sm)

print(total_num)
```

I'm not satisfied with this logic, and I believe there are better ways to do it.

Comment: How fast do you want your program to run anyways? Any restrictions? Also, consider visiting [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for optimization questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic doesn't work when 3rd iteration is needed. For example if your input is `99999999999`, your result is `18`. You need a loop:

```
n = input('Please enter the number: ')

while len(n) > 1:                 # If string length is 1, then stop
    numlist = [int(x) for x in n] # Makes an integer list from all chars in the input string
    n = str(sum(numlist))         # Sum and parse to string

print(n)
```

Input:

```
99999999999
```

Output:

```
9
```